# How can I insert a list of items in a mongodb document?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a list of lists formed this way: `list_of_lists[x, y, mean, variance]`.

- x equal 2 lists containing Latitude1 and Longitude1 of point x.
- y equal 2 lists containing Latitude2 and Longitude2 of the y point.
- mean equal 1 list containing the average of each link x -> y.
- variance equal 1 list created by the average to calculate the
  variance of each link x -> y.

  That is in this way:

```
Output: [[(37.94751, 15.3683), (37.95751, 15.3673), 3.3333333333333335, 0.22222222222222143], [(37.99751, 15.3663), (37.9474, 15.3653), 10.5, 6.25], [(37.95751, 15.3673), (37.99751, 15.3663), 4.0, 0.0]])
```

That said I would like to insert list_of_lists into a collection of mongodb by assigning each row of the list to a document. My problem is that I can not individually access all the fields on my list in order to build a document like this:

[image: Document mongodb]

With these code I can assign each line of a list to a document but I would like to be able to access the individual fields in such a way as to save them with the scheme shown above. Even if I use `list_of_lists [0] [0] [0]` I can not access all fields.

```
for u in range(len(list_of_lists)):
document = {'Link': list_of_lists[0]}
result = mycol2.insert_one(document)
```

I hope I explained myself. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
list_of_results = [[(37.94751, 15.3683), (37.95751, 15.3673), 3.3333333333333335, 0.22222222222222143], [(37.99751, 15.3663), (37.9474, 15.3653), 10.5, 6.25], [(37.95751, 15.3673), (37.99751, 15.3663), 4.0, 0.0]]

for item in list_of_results:
    document = {
        'Lat1' : item[0][0],
        'Lat2' : item[1][0],
        'Long1' : item[0][1],
        'Long2' : item[1][1],
        'Tempo Medio' : item[2],
        'Variance' : item[3]
    }
    result = mycol2.insert_one(document)
```

Comment: I had thought about making lists and then assigning them to various fields but it was very expensive both in terms of memory and time. Perfect. Thank you so much you have solved my problem. Good day.

Comment: Glad I could help!